# Share samba / windows file server links in emails, so they work on windows and linux (and mac)

Tags: linux, windows, samba

How can we share links to windows file system locations so they work in Windows, Linux and Macs when possible.

This is about a format that works accross platfoms (windows: \server\share\file or often DriveLetter:\file vs. Linux smb://server/share/file) as well as how to generate the links easily.

Comment: Use `file:///...`

Comment: How can I create such a link from windows?

Comment: Type it in the explorer search bar? Use an html link?

Comment: I mean, how to tell non-technical users to copy&paste such a link... is  there are tool? Does it work from outlook to click such a link?

Comment: It should work from any program that understands clicking on links.

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution seems to be to copy a file on a Windows share and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> in Outlook (insert hyperlink).

This makes as file like `S:/myfile.txt` to `file:///server/share/myfile.txt`

Such a link should work across systems.

Pretty cool :-)

Comment: that doesn't work for me. Pasting `\\server\share\myfile.txt` to Outlook will result in `file:///\\server\share\myfile.txt` which is not a universal link. The correct one would be `file://server/share/myfile.txt`

Comment: Did you use ctrl+K?

Comment: Ctrl+K or not, it results the same, because Outlook automatically corrects paths to links

Answer (score 5):

Use [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

```
scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]
```

> ## Proper Syntax
>
> For the UNC Windows file path
>
> ```
> \\laptop\My Documents\FileSchemeURIs.doc
> ```
>
> The corresponding valid file URI in Windows is the following:
>
> ```
> file://laptop/My%20Documents/FileSchemeURIs.doc
> ```

[File URIs in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/file-uris-in-windows)

---

> ## Unix
>
> Here are two Unix examples pointing to the same /etc/fstab file:
>
> ```
> file://localhost/etc/fstab
> file:///etc/fstab
> ```
>
> ## Windows
>
> Here are some examples which may be accepted by some applications on Windows systems, referring to the same, local file c:\WINDOWS\clock.avi
>
> ```
> file://localhost/c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> file:///c:/WINDOWS/clock.avi
> ```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

You can use some scripts [like this](https://superuser.com/q/1116771/241386) to convert those backslashes or just manually edit them

Alternatively use [Path Copy Copy](https://pathcopycopy.github.io/) which allows you to copy various types of names like short name, long name, folder name only, file name only, UNC path... You can even create your own type of path to copy with a regex

[image: Path Copy Copy]

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this for myself, but never could get the link to open explorer on the directory or file.  Looked up and down how to enable allowing my email client (an old thunderbird) to open file links with the default app, but no luck.  The HTML works if I past the link into the windows 'run' box -- so windows will open the the link with the correct application.  Had expanded it from there but I have cross client+server links that work so it wouldn't be hard to do the rest.  But it depends on getting the links to open in my email client:  `

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head></head>
<body bgcolor="#f8e8ff" text="#004040">

<br /><a href="file:///T:/Library/_CurrentSeason/_Kenja no Mago/[HorribleSubs] Kenja no Mago - 12 [720p].mkv">T:/Library/_CurrentSeason/_Kenja no Mago/[HorribleSubs] Kenja no Mago - 12 [720p].mkv</a>
<br /><a href="file:///T:/Library/_CurrentSeason/_Tate no Yuusha no Nariagari_;_herosSaveDay/[HorribleSubs] Tate no Yuusha no Nariagari - 25 [720p].mkv">T:/Library/_CurrentSeason/_Tate no Yuusha no Nariagari_;_herosSaveDay/[HorribleSubs] Tate no Yuusha no Nariagari - 25 [720p].mkv</a></body></html>
```

`

The links work, on Windows, and was mailed to me by a linux script that runs periodically and sends me notifications.  I don't have a desktop on linux (I run 'X', that displays on my Win machine).  But trying to open the link on linux would be pointless (as it has no desktop nor good media handling), and Mac would be more pointless as I don't have that.

I do have file system links that work on linux, and on windows, but not sure if that's useful... All of these things, though, are unique to my setup and my paths.
So I'm a bit confused as to what you are actually wanting.

Don't try to open URL links with backslashes in them.  Windows uses forward slashes for URL's.  Also, you can't have the same links on each system unless their file systems have a similar structure.  However, you can use symlinks to get around that.

Some examples from Cygwin/Windows/linux on my Windows root dir:

```
cygwin: (/)
D/
Documents -> //Bliss/Documents/
M/
Share -> /S/
S/
T/

windows DIR (c:)

D -> /??/UNC/Bliss/Documents
Documents -> /??/UNC/Bliss/Documents
M -> /??/UNC/Ishtar/Music/Anime
P -> /??/D:/Pictures
Share -> /??/S:/

linux: (/Athenae)
D -> /??/UNC/Bliss/Documents/
Documents -> /??/UNC/Bliss/Documents/
M -> /??/UNC/Ishtar/Music/Anime/
P -> /??/D:/Pictures/
S/
T/
```

The plain 'S/' can be viewed on any of the above with Cyg+win using /s/ and on linux '/Athenae/S' (S is really a linux dir /Share, so going through /Athenae/S goes to the windows workstation to get the files which asks for them from the linux box.

Since some of the windows links use /??/, I created a directory on linux
with the name of 2 question marks:
??/, so on linux

```
> ll '/??/UNC'   #gives:
lrwxrwxrwx 1  6 Feb 28  2015 Bliss -> Ishtar/
drwxrwx--- 2 61 Feb 28  2015 Ishtar/
lrwxrwxrwx 1  6 Feb 28  2015 ishtar -> Ishtar/
```

that way, windows links being shown on linux will take me to the right place.

All that symlink mumbo-jumbo is to make the same pathname work on my linux
and on my windows box (which was part of your question), as it was my
way of making sure the file-path portions of things could be seen from the same pathnames.

To do what you want can be complicated unless you force some simple common directories to be the same on every system.

To open the links in email...ARG....I don't know how to override the security restrictions, as the link, when copied from the email into the WIN-R (Run prompt) works correctly.

Anyone with an idea of how to get a local link to open in email (something that should have been possible enabling the file proto, but that didn't work. (sigh).